# What kind of language is used to develop Oracle's Smart View

Tags: oracle, hyperion, essbase

It is a very complex Excel add-on. I am wondering if all the functionalities are built using C#, C++, or Visual Basic? The typical interface is shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart View is written in C++. It descends from the classic Essbase Excel Add-in, which was also written in C++ and even predates the advent of the C# language. Also, the Excel development kit for writing plugins is most conducive to C++ programming rather than C#.